# Fresh cowdung and baggase in lasagna gardening

Tags: compost, container-gardening, urban-gardening

I am an apartment balcony gardener. I have access to a lot of fresh cowdung and baggase. However, I have no place to dry it or let it mature properly. I could dry it in my little balcony but the smell would attract undesirable pests. Can I use it directly in my lasagna gardening layer which I set up in an old plastic drum or is it better to compost it first? I do anerobic composting in the corner of my little balcony. Kindly suggest some ideas.

Comment: You need to let it dry.

Answer (score 2):

Fresh cowdung can not be used directly. It will rot, give birth to fungus and adversely affect soil quality. Since you have space constraints and smell factors, it's best to use dried cowdung. In case you are sourcing cow dung from a local dairy farm, ask them for dried  one. Almost all dairy farms keep piles of cowdung which gets dried up in few days. This dried cowdung can be used along with bagasse and a few earthworms.